# How to write jasmine script for below script

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have function which takes two parameters as input (each i/p is a array of objects).

```
eliminateduplicate(arr1 , arr2) {
    const difference = [];
    arr1.forEach(el1 => {
      const el1IsPresentInArr2 = arr2.some(el2 => el2.title === el1.title);
      if (!el1IsPresentInArr2) {
        difference.push(el1);
      }
    });
    return difference;
  }
```

I am new to jasmine scripting. How to write a jasmine unit test case for this function ? I am getting an warning also In case path not taken for 'if condition'.

Answer (score 0):

You could start reading https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/your_first_suite.

Once you've done this, you'll probably create a test suite that could look as follows. In the end, it should contain a test for all possible types of argument combinations (including border cases), your function may be called with. *Given-When-Then* style is optional but it helps in creating clearly structured tests.

```
describe('eliminateduplicate test suite', () => {

    it('#eliminateduplicate should return non-null array', () => {

        // given
        const arr = [...];  // define array

        // when
        const result = eliminateduplicate(arr, null); 

        // then
        expect(result).toBe(arr);
    });

    it('#eliminateduplicate should return array when both arrays are same', () => {

        // given
        const arr = [...];  // define array

        // when
        const result = eliminateduplicate(arr, arr); 

        // then
        expect(result).toBe(arr);
    });

    it('#eliminateduplicate should return array with unique elements only', () => {

        // given
        const arr1 = [...];  // define array arr1
        const arr2 = [...];  // define array arr2 

        // when
        const result = eliminateduplicate(arr1, arr2); 

        // then
        const expected = [...];  // define expected result
        expect(result).toEqual(expected);
    });

    ...

});
```